# how to change the position of div when click on it and move it as it was when click it another time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to click on div 15 to move it to the position of hidden div, And vice versa for hidden Div, when click on hidden Div move it to the position of Div 15 as it was .

The jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6paRL/12/

HTML

```
<div id="numbers15">15</div>
<div id="hidden"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#numbers15").click(function()
    {
        $("#numbers15").animate(
        {
            'left': '195px',
            'top': '195px'
        })

        $("#hidden").animate(
        {
            'left': '134px',
            'top': '195px'
        }) 
    })
});
```

Comment: I already modified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#numbers15").click(function(){
        var l1=$("#numbers15").css('left')=='134px'?'195px':'134px';
        var l2=$("#hidden").css('left')=='134px'?'195px':'134px';
    $("#numbers15").animate({
        'left': l1,
         'top': '195px'
  })
    $("#hidden").animate({
        'left': l2,
         'top': '195px'
  })
  })
});
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/6paRL/14/)**

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: you could try this simple approach

Answer (score 2):

Check this solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/6paRL/13/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#numbers15").click(function(){
      if ( $(this).hasClass('after')){
        $(this).removeClass('after');
        $("#numbers15").animate({
          'left': '134px',
           'top': '195px'
        });
        $("#hidden").animate({
          'left': '195px',
          'top': '195px'
        });            
     }else{
        $(this).addClass('after');
        $("#numbers15").animate({
          'left': '195px',
          'top': '195px'
        });
        $("#hidden").animate({
          'left': '134px',
          'top': '195px'
        });
     }
  })
});
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you are doing? Wall of code and jsfiddle isn't a very good answer.

Comment: I'm minimalist. This is very simple code so I think there is nothing to explain. If anything is not clear I will, but not before that. What do you think I should explain, addClass, animate, or repeat function in other way (way back) ?

Comment: In my opinion there is always room for explanation. It was an improvement suggestion, not a demand. Do as you see fit.

Comment: Ok will work on this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use data attribute on every div containing the original position.
**Example**:

```
<div id="numbers15" data-posX="20" data-posY="20">
```

Than, onclick, you add a class.
If the div doesn't already have the class, do the original animation.
 if it has it, than make the animation with the data attributes instead.